# Upload an excel file read the data from file and insert it into database using spring boot rest api

Tags: java, oracle11g, apache-poi, multipartform-data

**I want to develope an rest api which will take excel sheet as an multipart object read the content in the file and upload it to the oracle database.**
untill now what i did is:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                 @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        try {

            ExcelController ex=new ExcelController();
            File f1=ex.convert(file);
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(f1);
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                    //getCellTypeEnum shown as deprecated for version 3.15
                    //getCellTypeEnum ill be renamed to getCellType starting from version 4.0
                    if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
                    } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
                    }

                }
                System.out.println();

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks good. Are you having a problem? Please consider providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you explain which part does / does not work

Comment: I m having problem in the approach to insert data from this iteration to database.

Answer (score 1):

You will need your connection string, as well as a stored procedure that does the insert (and possibly returns a token or maybe a new unique identifier):

```
String sp = "{call spInsertRecord(?, ?)}";
try (Connection con = /* you get your connection here*/) {
    if (con != null) {
        try (CallableStatement cStatement = con.prepareCall(sp)) {
            if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING)
                cStatement.setLong("columnString", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
            else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC)
                cStatement.setLong("columnLong", currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
            try (ResultSet rs = cStatement.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs != null) {
                    // do something with your return value if you have any
                    rs.close();
                } else {
                    log.error("Exception in myMethod: [ResultSet is null]");
                }
            }
            cStatement.close();
        }
    } else {
        log.error("Exception in myMethod.getConnection(): [Connection is null]");
    }

}
```

You can find more on how to create Oracle connection [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-oracle-database)

Answer (score 0):

Here I am writing logic to read data row by row and check every cell value based on value populate DB Entity object to persist in your oracle DB.

```
private ProductEntity createAndPopulateEntity(Row recordRow,List<BulkProductDetailResponse.ErrorDetail> processingError) {
    List<String> headerNames = Arrays.asList("Index", "Prouduct", "Time", "Year");
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
    int MANDATORY_FIELDS_INDEX_LIMIT = 3;
    ProductEntity entity = new ProductEntity();
    int cellCount = 0;
    for (Cell cellData : recordRow) {
        String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cellData);
        if (cellCount <= MANDATORY_FIELDS_INDEX_LIMIT) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cellValue)) {
                switch (cellCount) {
                    case 0:
                        if (cellData.getCellType().equals(CellType.STRING)) {
                            entity.setTitle(cellValue);
                            cellCount++;
                        } else {
                            BulkProductDetailResponse.ErrorDetail error = new BulkProductDetailResponse
                                    .ErrorDetail(BulkProductDetailResponse.ValidationsType.INVALID_VALUES.getValue(), cellData.getRowIndex(), "Column:[" + headerNames.get(cellCount) + "] value data type is not expected.");
                            processingError.add(error);
                            cellCount++;
                        }
                        continue;
                    case 1:
                        if (cellData.getCellType().equals(CellType.STRING)) {
                            entity.setProductName(cellValue);
                            cellCount++;
                        } else {
                            BulkProductDetailResponse.ErrorDetail error = new BulkProductDetailResponse
                                    .ErrorDetail(BulkProductDetailResponse.ValidationsType.INVALID_VALUES.getValue(), cellData.getRowIndex(), "Column:[" + headerNames.get(cellCount) + "] value data type is not expected.");
                            processingError.add(error);
                            cellCount++;
                        }
                        continue;
                    case 2:
                        if (cellData.getCellType().equals(CellType.STRING)) {
                            entity.setPeriod(cellValue);
                            cellCount++;
                        } else {
                            BulkProductDetailResponse.ErrorDetail error = new BulkProductDetailResponse
                                    .ErrorDetail(BulkProductDetailResponse.ValidationsType.INVALID_VALUES.getValue(), cellData.getRowIndex(), "Column:[" + headerNames.get(cellCount) + "] value data type is not expected.");
                            processingError.add(error);
                            cellCount++;
                        }
                        continue;
                    case 3:
                        if (cellData.getCellType().equals(CellType.NUMERIC)) {
                            entity.setYear(Integer.parseInt(cellValue));
                            cellCount++;
                        } else {
                            BulkProductDetailResponse.ErrorDetail error = new BulkProductDetailResponse
                                    .ErrorDetail(BulkProductDetailResponse.ValidationsType.INVALID_VALUES.getValue(), cellData.getRowIndex(), "Column:[" + headerNames.get(cellCount) + "] value data type is not expected.");
                            processingError.add(error);
                            cellCount++;
                        }
                        continue;

                }

            } else {
                log.debug("Column value can not be blank for column:[" + headerNames.get(cellCount) + "].");
                BulkProductDetailResponse.ErrorDetail error = new BulkProductDetailResponse
                        .ErrorDetail(BulkProductDetailResponse.ValidationsType.INVALID_VALUES.getValue(), cellData.getRowIndex(), "Column:[" + headerNames.get(cellCount) + "] value can not be blank for \"CPI\", \"Portfolio\", \"Time Period\" and \"Year\".");
                processingError.add(error);
                cellCount++;
                continue;
            }
        } 
    }
    return entity;
}
```